# creating objects and naming them at runtime in C++

Tags: c++

Actually I'm making a budget calculating app, where there is a class for the items I buy.

```
class Item
{
    string name;
    string date;
    int amount;
    float singlePrice;
    float totalPrice;
    // constructor
    Public Item(string name, int amount, float price)
    {
        
    }
};
```

But I don't want to hard code every Item, I want to add items in the app and save it to file and calculate how much money I have left.

Comment: Choose a collection that can be modified and store the `Bought`s in there. Some are more suitable depending on how you want to access the data but you've got some options, (vector, unordered_map, ...). Other than the choice of data stucture there's another important choice you  need to make: how do you persist the data? Database, file, ...?

Comment: Note that your constructor is private here, which probably is not what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put them in an appropriate data structure which will let you retrieve them by name later on.

Put them in a `std::map<string, Bought>` if there's going to be just one instance of each, otherwise, in a `std::map<string, std::vector<Bought>>` if needed; although, your data model really should have a notion of quantity too somewhere - i.e., separate your item catalog from a purchase itself.